# Assign special keys in Tails

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tails-os

Is there a way to assign/switch function of special keys (Shift, CapsLock, Control).

I want to switch Control with CapsLock, i.e. I want physical Control key to work as CapsLock and physical CapsLock key as Control.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Tails. This is about the Gnome desktop environment. The problem is that even if you do find out how to do that, those settings will not be automatically saved after reboot so you will need to find a way to redo it every time you reboot.

Comment: Redo unless I use root account to modify files on Tails USB stick. That is why I am asking here. There is keyboard selection screen before booting Tails.